# ASP.NET Core API - Why does logger type match controller class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In this code example for creating a logging instance using Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core why is the logger type the controller class when injecting the logger in the constructor?

```
ILogger<TodoController> logger
```

Instead of `ILogger<TodoController>` shouldn't it be just `ILogger logger` passed into the constructor?

Code example:

```
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITodoRepository _todoRepository;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository,
        ILogger<TodoController> logger)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @JohnB LOL not an error

Comment: I think it's ILogger<TCategoryName> and not ILogger<T>... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: ah - thanks for the correction!

Comment: You need to also add some code in your `Startup.cs` to configure the dependency injection.   Your code sample only shows the portion of the code where you are retrieving the objects governed by dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at some of the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-logs):

```
_logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.GetItem, "Getting item {ID}", id);
```

Then the corresponding [sample output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.2#sample-logging-output):

```
info: TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController[1002]
      Getting item 0
```

Notice that the name of the controller is included even though it wasn't specified in the call to `LogInformation`?

That's why. It lets the logger automatically include the class that logged the information.

Comment: So it's not T as Type which is what I was thinking. It's ILogger<TCategoryName> which tells the logger which class to put in the logger output...it's not used for Dependency Injection to determine logger type. Cool, I understand now, thanks!